# Red language console error: libreadline.so.6: cannot open shared object file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, console, red

I'm new to the Red programming language.

I tried to test it by downloading the Linux binary.  But when I execute it on the console, I get an error that says:

```
root@xxx-linux:/home/xxx/Downloads# ./red-042
Pre-compiling Red console...
/tmp/red/console: error while loading shared libraries:
libreadline.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I searched on Google for this error, but couldn't find anything.

My operating system is 64-bit Linux Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I succeeded to make it work using this command on Ubuntu, which installs 32bit "multilib" version of `libreadline`:

```
sudo apt-get install libreadline6:i386
```

Answer (score 3):

32bit version of libreadline is required. There is already work to replace this dependency here https://github.com/qtxie/red/tree/new-console but it was not merged to the master yet.

Answer (score 0):

I also came across this issue after upgrading to 64 bit Ubuntu 18.04, and after spending some time looking into the issue I found that after upgrade libreadline package was missing, so I installed libreadline package using

```
sudo apt-get install libreadline-dev
```

But this also didn't solve my problem. Then I figured out that it installed the upgraded version of the libreadline package i.e libreadline.so.7.0. As a workaround I created its symlink so I can continue my work with libreadline.so.6.

```
$ cd /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
$ sudo ln -s libreadline.so.7.0 libreadline.so.6
```

And this worked wonders and my problem with libreadline package was solved.